How to despawn and spawn a model
I am making a small Point-and-click slice for a project I am working on.
Intentionally aiming for something very simple and easy to do.
My goal is essentially a First person PoV 3D game, where you don't move from the spot, but move between rooms and interact with NPCs.
Upon entering a room, you are supposed to locate the NPC (very easily) and click on them.
Causing the NPC to despawn and then respawn right in front of the camera.
And that is my problem.
I can't seem to find any good sources or instructions (or ideas) on how to despawn/spawn a model.
The idea is simple:
Screenshot of basic pure programming stage of development:

Click on the distant model (The blue cylinder).
The blue cylinder despawn/goes inactive.
Then the blue cylinder right in front of the camera spawns/becomes active.
And then the player is (supposed) to be able to do the same but in reverse.
(Aka, click on the model in front of the player, the model disappears and the previous one returns)
I have honestly not really managed to get anywhere.
I have tried to find sources for spawning or despawning and so on, but almost all sources I find talk exclusively about it from a perspective of spawning obstacles or repeated multiple or randomized spawning.
And I just can't seem to find anything reliable for me to go after.
(Maybe just me who can't properly find what I am looking for)

why despawn and respawn, why not just move?

So what exactly have you tried and where is the issue? ... for actually spawn something you use Instantiate and Destroy accordingly ... or for properly reusing the already existing instances you just use SetActive ...

Probably the most popular way of "despawn, and respawn" is to not despawn it at all. Many games give the illusion of "despawn" but in reality, they just move it or set it to inactive. This way saves memory at runtime since there is no need to create/destroy anything. An example of this would be:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DespawnRespawn : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform object1;
    public Transform object2;

    void Update() {
        //if user presses left mouse button
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            //if player is looking at object1, despawn object1 and respawn object2
            if (Vector3.Dot(Camera.main.transform.forward, object1.position - Camera.main.transform.position) > 0) {
                object1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                object2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }

            //if player is looking at object2, despawn object2 and respawn object1
            if (Vector3.Dot(Camera.main.transform.forward, object2.position - Camera.main.transform.position) > 0) {
                object2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                object1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
    }
}

However, if you want to truly instantiate an object(Create a new object) at runtime, you use instantiate. You can learn more about instantiate here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html
Here is an example of the second way:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DespawnRespawn : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject aliveObject;//the currently visible object
    public GameObject prefab; //asset you want to spawn in

    public Vector3 spawnPosition1;
    public Vector3 spawnPosition2;
    void Update() {
        //if user presses left mouse button
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            //if player is looking at aliveObject, destroy aliveObject and respawn new aliveObject at spawnPosition2
            if (Vector3.Dot(Camera.main.transform.forward, aliveObject.position - Camera.main.transform.position) > 0) {
            bool wasAtSpawnPosition1 = aliveObject.transform.position == spawnPosition1;

            Destroy(aliveObject);
            if(wasAtSpawnPosition1)
                aliveObject = Instantiate(prefab, spawnPosition2, Quaternion.identity);
            else
                aliveObject = Instantiate(prefab, spawnPosition1, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
}

